# React native know if a specific port is open on your device

Tags: android, ios, react-native, port, metro-bundler

The following kotlin code lets you know if port `7001` is in use.

Is there any way to know about react native on both ios and android.

```java
fun checkPort(): Boolean {
    return try {
        Socket("localhost", 7001).use { true }
    } catch(ignored: IOException) {
        false
    }
}
```

Comment: On iOS, unless your app is using the port it isn't in use because apps can't listen on network ports in the background.